# Image class handling in Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having trouble to edit a profile on my application because image field is returning this error:

> Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "MainBundle\Entity\Image" given

Here is my RegistrationEditFormType class:

```
class RegistrationEditFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('lastName', 'text')
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('phone', 'text')
            ->add('amount', 'money')
            ->add('image',        new \MainBundle\Entity\Image(), array(
            'required' => false,
                'data_class' => null
                )
            )
        ;
    }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'lldcontribution_userbundle_registration_edit';
}
```

}

Previously I tried:

```
->add('image',        ImageType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
                'data_class' => null
            )
        )
```

And get this error:

> Expected argument of type "MainBundle\Entity\Image", "array" given

Other informations:

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('file', 'file', array('data_class' => null))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MainBundle\Entity\Image'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'lldcontribution_mainbundle_image';
    }
}
```

The action of the controller that is using the form:

```
/**
 * Edit the user
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    //die('ok');
    //$user = $this->getUser();

    //$id = $request->request->get('id');



    $user = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
        ->find($id)
    ;

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (!is_object($user) || !($user instanceof UserInterface)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    //$formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

    //$form = $formFactory->createForm();

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationEditFormType(), $user);
    //$form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {


        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $amount = $request->request->get('amount');

        $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
        $user->setFirstName($request->request->get('firstName'));
        $user->setLastName($request->request->get('lastName'));
        $user->setPhone($request->request->get('phone'));
        $user->setAmount($request->request->get('amount'));
        $user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

        //var_dump($user);die();

        // Updating the user
        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

        //$userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('lld_admin');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info-edit', 'Your account has been updated!');
    return $this->render('UserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user
    ));
}
```

I'm using Symfony2.8 and PHP 5.6. I'm stuck and don't know what is wrong, especially since I'm used making use of my Image class without any problems. What am I missing out? Any suggestions?

Comment: The form builder (first code) expects a form type (string or class) as second argument in add(), not an entity.

Comment: Please include your Controller code that is using the form(s). It looks like you have two different error points. One is on the initial form, the other is on the child form type after you made the change.

Comment: @fyrye I've added the controller action using the form

Comment: Use FileType::class instead of the second 'file' in buildForm of ImageType.